# Javascript ajax response text parsing only the JSON portion

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to parse my response text which contains JSON. I was wondering if there is any way to use regex in javascript to start parsing JSON from the beginning `{` to ending `}` Is there an easier way to do this?

Here is my js:

```
function getStatus(){
$.ajax({
      url:"../lib/getstatus.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
          name: name
      },
      dataType: "text", 
      success:function(result){
          console.log(result);
      }
  });
}
```

Here is a sample of my response text.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Tue, 20 Mar 2018 00:28:38 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

{"myJson: response",      //need to start parsing from here and ignore the top returned headers.
...
}
```

Comment: can you post the code of your call in js ?

Comment: then you need to parse the response BODY

Comment: @kip ajax updated above.

Comment: @JaromandaX is there a javascript function to do just the BODY?

Comment: What is this result printed in console? console.log(result); This should be body

Comment: Headers are not part of the HTTP response body.

Comment: @kkmoslehpour if you `console.log()` show the response that you posted, I think that the problem is the server because you only need the JSON response without headers

Comment: if `result` that you `console.log` in your code includes the headers, then the server is sending rubbish

Comment: @GaurangDave that whole thing starting from `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` is the console.log response. I just want the bottom JSON part.

Comment: the issue is with server side code - post that

Comment: if you can't fix the server, then try something like `var json = result.split(/\r?\n\r?\n/).slice(1).join('\n')` ... or `result.split(/(\r?\n){2}/).slice(1).join('')`

Comment: or, if you're sure `{` will never appear in the headers ... `result.substr(result.indexOf('{'))`

Comment: @JaromandaX Ah okay, I think I got it now. In my php I'm going to have to add `$jsonStart = "{"` at the end and then do this `echo strstr($result, $jsonStart)`. But it is also good to know that you could do it with `.split`. I wasn't sure if javascript supported regex like bash.

Comment: You are awsome! @JaromandaX

Comment: To be honest, I'd fix the PHP to not send headers in the response body :p

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't have control over that, but is there a reason why changing it in the server side code is preferred?

Comment: because sending response headers in the response body is complete garbage :p